# Async function returning promise but console.log does give out the result as wanted | NodeJS Own Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, async-await, module

I just wrote a simple and small API to define the gender of a person. It works via a get-request to a page which gives me back a JSON object.

This is the code of my module:

```js
'use strict';
const https = require('https');

exports.getGender = function (name) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //send request to api
    https.get(`https://api.genderize.io?name=${name}`, (resp) => {
      var data = '';
      //replace data
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      //define information on end of query
      resp.on('end', () => {
        var info = JSON.parse(data);
        //check accuracy of gender
        if (info.probability >= 0.8) {
          //check gender
          if (info.gender == 'male') {
            resolve('Sehr geehrter Herr');
          } else if (info.gender == 'female') {
            resolve('Sehr geehrte Frau');
          }
        } else {
          resolve('Sehr geehrte/r Frau / Herr');
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

And this is the call I do in the main file:

```js
//get gender of person
async function getG(name) {
  const data = await genderApi.getGender(name);
  return data;
}

getG('Tim');
```

But the output is just `Promise { <pending> }`, If I replace the `return data` with a `console.log(data)` it just works fine and it shows me the output in the console but I really need it to return the value cause later on I use this function in a text back to the user

Answer (score 0):

`getG` function is also async so you must use with `await` keyword or `.then` callback

```js
const val = await getG('Tim');
// or
getG('Tim').then((val) => {
 console.log(val)
})
```

Comment: the first solution does not work because await just works inside a async function and the other one does also just return Promise <Pending>

Comment: Yes async function works inside async function but you can use *self-invoking function* like `(async () => {const val = await getG('Tim')})()`.

Comment: well I tried it but its also not working for me :(